# owl slider 2 show next slide cropped

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, slider, owl-carousel

i am trying to add a mobile optimized slider to my website. therefore i don't want to show the next / prev buttons. I want to show the first / current slide in total and the second / next slide cropped.

I have seen owl slider gives you an option to have a stagepadding: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/stagepadding.html

Is it possible to have the padding only on the right side, so my idea of the slider would be real. I don't want to show the previous and the next slide cropped, just the next slide.

hope you guys (and girls) can help me.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve it by adding a negative right: of stagePadding's value on .owl-stage class. **(Not tested)**
For example, if stagePadding: 20:

```
.owl-stage {
    right: -10px;
}
```

Originally answer: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/172#issuecomment-62762886

Comment: I had to use the positive value (right:10) but that's the solution. Thank you very much!